# Sharepoint 2010 Javascript error on trying to add webpart to custom page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I deployed a custom page and when I edit it, trying to add a webpart, I get the following javascript error:

> Message: 'this._cats[...]' is null or not an object
>   Line: 2
>   Char: 3404
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://devpn-004:2010/_layouts/wpadder.js?rev=hnGJJEMcU5XH%2BCq7PlSxJw%3D%3D (not a valid link 2013-12-09)

Comment: you should provide more information. `this._cats` seems to be some custom code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh reinstall of Sharepoint 2010 fixed this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, in real life it's often impossible to just kill and restart a server.